# How to create a session token programmatically in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, runtime-error

I need to create a new Session Token in wordpress programmatically, I'm a little newby in the world of wordpress.

I'm using the class `WP_Session_Tokens` to do this, here are the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_session_tokens/create/

I have this code but doesn't work and I don't know what is happening, could someone help me pls?

**Example 1**:

```
if ($sessionToken = WP_Session_Tokens::create($expirationDate))
{
    return $sessionToken;
}
```

**Example 2**:

```
$sessionToken = new WP_Session_Tokens($user->ID);
$sessionToken = $sessionToken->create($expirationDate);
```

I'm getting error 500 and I can't turn on the debug mode to check what is the error, because I don't have access to the `wp_config.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Exploring other issues I found the solution to my problem, this code works to create a session token:

```php
$manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
$token   = $manager->create( $expiration );
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46009653/2) to the question [How to create a session token programmatically in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009653/how-to-create-a-session-token-programmatically-in-wordpress) by the OP [Radames E. Hernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5655917/radames-e-hernandez) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>